# Generate invoice number from 0 to so on for ordered products in orders table in php mysqli

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I am trying to generate invoice number in orders table, like if user select 1 or multiple products and add it to cart then place order then invoice number should be same in our orders table for that 1 order in multiple rows according to products.
I was using function `mt_rand();` but it generates randomly. I want to generate numbers from 0 to so on.
Like, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and so on.
**I've also tried this to generate invoice number.**
**$i++**

```
$squery = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$sresult = $this->db->select($squery);
if($sresult){
    $totalPrice = 0;
    $i = 0;
    while($svalue = $sresult->fetch_assoc()){
        $i++;
        $pro_id = $svalue['pro_id'];
        $pro_name = $svalue['pro_name'];
        $quantity = $svalue['quantity'];
        $pro_price = $svalue['pro_price'] * $quantity;
        $pro_image = $svalue['pro_image'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO orders(user_id, pro_id, invoice_no, pro_name, status, date) "
                . "VALUES('$user_id', '$pro_id', '$i', '$pro_name', 'processing', NOW())";
        $result = $this->db->insert($query);
        if($result){
            header("location: orders-list.php");
        } else {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Something's went wrong. Please try again.</div>";
            return $msg;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't inserts same number in multiple ordered products rows of 1 order.
Please help me how can i generate invoice number from 0 to so on.

Comment: this question should have been asked on https://stackoverflow.com/ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the MySQL database to calculate order numbers for you using a self populating [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) integer column.

Separate out your order table into two distinct tables. One for the order top line details (e.g. order number, customer details) and a second for the order specifics (item, quantity, item ID etc.).

This way you could then insert a line into the first table to 'create' the order. Then you can query the database to get the OrderNumber for this order. Then use that to populate the table containing the details of the order.

There's a very rough example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76edde).

You can then get the order ID using this query

```
select OrderNumber from Orders where CustomerID = 57
order by OrderDate DESC limit 1;
```

and get all of the order items with this one:

```
select * from OrderDetails where ordernumber = 1;
```

To get all info in one request, assuming you have the OrderNumber, can be done like this:

```
Select o.OrderNumber
  ,o.CustomerID
  ,o.BillingAddressID
  ,o.OrderDate
  ,o.OrderStatus
  ,od.pro_id
  ,od.pro_name
  from Orders o
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails od
    on o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber
      where o.OrderNumber = 1
```

Without knowing your exact code workflow and customer journey it's hard to say what will work best. You will have to figure that out.

I'd definitely recommend on reading up about [normalising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data so you can create the best data structure for your needs.

Comment: 2 tables? then how can i merge them?

Comment: and how can i insert in two tables when user click on place order

Comment: @ZainMedia With two tables you can either make two requests. Once to get the order ID and main details followed by one to get the item details. Or you could make one single request using the `JOIN` clause.

I'm not sure the example I gave saved properly so I'll update my answer with some extra details as it also shows the insert.

There's no right or wrong way to do it. You know your user's journey but you can make as many SQL calls as you need in your WHILE loop.

Comment: yeah  but now, there is 2 tables, order and order_details. I think i should not insert orders table in while loop, coz it will then insert multiple rows, in while loop, i should only insert order_details

Comment: Yes - creating the Order should happen outside of the loop.

Comment: Made changes then it worked but your answer helped me a lot to think like this and to do this properly. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ZainMedia this answer is not totally correct`select OrderNumber from Orders where CustomerID = 57
order by OrderDate DESC limit 1;`  want does this do? I mean what happens if the CustomerID  57 happens to have multiple equal OrderDate values how to you know for sure which OrderNumber you get as result as it can be one of all those matches... This `ORDER BY` here is non deterministic ("random") to get a deterministic (fixed) result on every run you should alteast add a column with a `PRIMARY/UNQIUE KEY` aswell in the `ORDER BY` to make it multicolumn sorting..

Comment: This is where I made an assumption for speed and clarity. That query isn't really the best way to get the order just placed. As you spotted there are times it could fail, like if that customer adds a second order by the time you ask for data from the first order.

I would create a stored procedure that takes the inputs from your cart, sanitises and checks those inputs, creates the order, add the items to the order then returns the OrderID to the PHP. Because this will all happen in one transaction you can be certain the order ID returned is the correct one.

Comment: no, this is not totally 100% correct but the idea was 100% correct. I made a few changes and worked 100% for me

Comment: SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY order_number DESC limit 1

Answer (score 0):

Okay, As per our discussion, what you want is
the same invoice number to, one order(one order can have multiple products but from one User).

So I think you need one table which can save the `Invoice Number` So when you are inserting into order table before that you fetch the `Invoice Number` and increment it, then you in `order table`

```
$INV_NUM = "SELECT INVOICE_NUMBER FROM INVOICE";
$INV_NUM++;

$squery = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$sresult = $this->db->select($squery);
if($sresult){
    $totalPrice = 0;
    $i = 0;
    while($svalue = $sresult->fetch_assoc()){
....................
....................
....................
 $query = "INSERT INTO orders(user_id, pro_id, invoice_no, pro_name, status, date) "
                . "VALUES('$user_id', '$pro_id', '$INV_NUM', '$pro_name', 'processing', NOW())";
....................
....................
```

This strategy might help you. Please let me know, it works or not?

Comment: No brother. This is not the answer. Kindly read my question carefully first

Comment: so what is going on, is there any entry in a database or not!??

Comment: so what you need? one `Invoice Id` for multiple products purchased by one user ?

Comment: yes, same invoice id for multiple products ordered by once that we called it 1 order includes multiple products. mt_rand() function do it but generates number random. I wanna generate from 1 to so on, 1 by 1,

Comment: KevH's answer was right brother. Proper way to do this.

Comment: You also might want to research what SQL injections (first (on runtime) and second order (stored) ) are as your code seams to be prone on atleast one those kind of attacks if not both..